# How to Read an Integer from a TextField

Tags: swiftui, integer

I am currently creating a simple app / program that calculates the average of the grades given. I was wondering how would I take the value given from text field and read it. I currently have the textfield assigned to the blank string 'testVar' but I need to read an integer in order to do calculations ie: all grades / # of classes.

I have linked an image as it in Swift it's just simply easier to read, especially to see the view I currently have.  [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPEfA.png)

Basically I was trying to ask is how would I read an integer from textfield or is there better way to do this (I am just working with what I am familiar with 'forms').

Any advice helps.

Comment: Have you tried, for example, `TextField("some text", value: $intValue, formatter: numberFormatter)`
See:  [Creating a text field with a value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield)  and specifically: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-3fh51  you can copy and paste the example code.

Comment: _Never_ post code as an image, always text.

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` has initialisers that allow you to use types other than `String`, by passing either a `format` or `formatter`.

In the example below, `format: .number` is used with an `Int` value:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State private var value: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Some number", value: $value, format: .number)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor code as an image, will import as text next time but how would I round numbers if it is a double.  For example: "let finalGrade = value1 + value2 ... / total. If all variables are a double how would I either round finalGrade into decimals before it prints as Text("\(finalGrade)") or would I be able to do that in Text statement.

Comment: Please ask that as another question